# Remap yank (y), Change (c) and Delete (d)

Tags: vim

I've been trying to extend the functionality of these three commands (y,c,d), so I'd have the content both in the system clipboard ("+ register) and in the normal registers.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
nnoremap Y y$v$"+y$
nnoremap yy 0y$0v$"+y$
vnoremap y ygv"+y
" ------
nnoremap C y$v$"+c
nnoremap cc 0y$0v$"+c
vnoremap c ygv"+c
" ------
nnoremap D y$v$"+d$
nnoremap dd 0y$0v$"+d$
vnoremap d ygv"+d
" ------
```

And I have a few issues with this mapping:

1. For some odd reason, I have to resource my .vimrc before I can actually use these new bindings. 
   Trying to use only nmap, vmap or even map just didn't seem to work at all.
2. When I try to yank (for example) multiple lines (e.g. 2yy), it yanks the text to the "regular" register ("0) as expected, but yanks only the first line into the system clipboard.
3. I could'nt find a way to create this behaviour to y,c and d in normal-mode.

Can anyone help solve these issues?

I thought of creating a function, perhaps, so I could call it multiple times, but my vim script-fu is novice at best.

Comment: You don't want to just use the system clipboard as the default register for all things?

Comment: Don't know, actually. I'm not too familiar with the concept of registers in vim yet, but I do know that if I force the yank into the "+ register it doesn't add up in the 1-9 registers as it originally should have. although it can be solved relatively easily with YankRing plugin, I just didn't want to restrain the original behavior. further more, to yank 2 lines I need to write "+2y, and not 2"+y I think. correct?

Comment: No, you have to type `"+2yy`: `"+` for the register, `2` and `yy` to yank the full line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can do `"+y`, all these mappings are useless. Just add `set clipboard+=unnamedplus` to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: actually I've tried that and it didn't seem to work. I'm using linux both with the command line vim and gvim. Perhaps command-line vim doesn't allow for the unnamed to be related with the system clipboard?

Comment: `unnamedplus` is a recent addition to Vim. My version (7.3.035, on Linux) doesn't have it while my recent MacVim (no idea what version) at work has it. To see if you can use it do `:h 'clipboard'` and see if it's listed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the unnamedplus now, and it works great. Together with YankRing it satisfies my needs.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but set `clipboard=unnamedplus` did, and for that, I could kiss you. THANK YOU!